# Where to connect tristate pin of oscillator?

Tags: oscillator

I'm trying to use this oscillator in a project but am unsure of how to connect the tristate pin.
I believe I should NC it but don't want to mess up my design if that is not the case.

https://ecsxtal.com/store/pdf/ECS-5032MV.pdf

```
Tri State Function

Pin 1                    Output  

0.7 * Vdd Min or NC      Active  
0.3 * Vdd Max.           High Impedance
```

Thanks!

Comment: I always thought that the pin is NC, that means, not connected to anything inside.  In other words, I always use three pins, Vcc, Ground, and oscillator output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct - leaving it open will enable the oscillator.

One way of covering your bases is to put a resistor in your PCB but don't stuff it if not needed. In this case, it would be between the tri-state pin and the positive power supply.

Putting such a component in the PCB also allows you to wire something to that point if you need to test it or to modify the operation of the circuit - if you just leave it as no-connect there will not be a pad to wire to.

In general, it is good practice to use a resistor if you ever need to pull a signal up to Vcc or down to ground, it provides flexibility in testing (for example you could disable the oscillator to inject another signal for testing) or easily modify the circuit.